# ContentManager in XNA cant find any XML

Tags: xna, c#, xna-content-pipeline, xml

Im making a game in XNA 4 and this is the first time I'm using the Content loader to initialize a simple class with a XML file, but no matter how many guide I follow, or how simple or complicated is my XML File the ContentManager cant find the file; the Debug keep telling me: "A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException' occurred in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll". 
I'm really confuse because I can load SpriteFonts and Texture2D without a problem ...

I create the following XML (the most basic Xna XML):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<XnaContent>
  <Asset Type="System.String">Hello</Asset>
</XnaContent>
```

and I try to load it in the LoadContent method in my main class like this:

```
System.String hello = Content.Load<System.String>("NewXmlFile");
```

There is something I'm doing wrong? I really appreciate your help

Comment: In the properties of your XML file, is the importer set correctly?

Comment: When asking about exceptions, as well as the *type* of the exception, please provide the *`Message`* property of the exception. For example, I can get this exception type by setting the filename incorrectly, with a message: "`Error loading "NewXmlFile". File not found.`". But I can't be sure that's the same exception you are getting!

Answer (score 1):

The code you have provided works fine.

Create a new XNA 4.0 Windows project. Right click on the *Content* project and add a new item. Choose "XML File". Open that created file and fill it with the content you have in your question.

Then add the line:

```
System.String hello = Content.Load<System.String>("NewXmlFile");
```

To your `LoadContent` method. Be sure that `NewXmlFile` is the filename of the XML file you created, *without* its file extension. For example, if you used the default name given to you when creating the file, above, you should replace `"NewXmlFile"` with `"XMLFile1"`.

Set a breakpoint on the line after your call to `Load`. Run your game, and observe in the debugger that the variable `hello` now contains your string.